# ActionScript - FlashMediaServer. Application on server side

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I need to create a small app on FSM to work only on server side and I have
a question:
If it possible to do such a thing?:

- application which will streaming video to clients
- on top of video put small spite with dynamically switching pic
- on clients side read it only as a video
- streaming also for iPhone/iPad devices

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You mean the dynamic pics are embed into the video ?

Comment: Yes, something over the video. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use "appendBytes" on the "NetStream" Class, so i believe you can edit raw video data on the fly yes. That would be quite server demanding if you do it on the server side, would be better on the client side i guess...

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. We change the idea and we will change everything before streaming to FMS.

Comment: I would have gone that road too :)